# Using CSS, select first N items matching a class, without a common parent

Tags: css, select, element, parent-child, children

Using CSS, is it possible to select the first N items matching a class, when they don't have a common parent? I know it is possible when they have a common parent, using `nth-child` I believe, but that only works when all the elements have a common parent, because that's the only case when they are siblings.

Here's an example of my specific situation. In this example, I want to select the `<li>` for tasks 1 to 5, using CSS. Possible?

```
<div id="todo-lists">
    <ul class="list">
        <li>Task 1</li>
        <li>Task 2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list">
        <li>Task 3</li>
        <li>Task 4</li>
        <li>Task 5</li>
        <li>Task 6</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list">
        <li>Task 7</li>
        <li>Task 8</li>
        <li>Task 9</li>
        <li>Task 10</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: In the general case, no. If you have a specific case in mind, show your HTML and there might be a way select the elements you want.

Comment: Okay I added an example in my OP.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do it here, sorry!